# AS3 Garbage Collection: removing everything from one point downwards

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my document class I have this code

```
_gameWorld = new GameWorld();
addChild(_gameWorld);
```

GameWorld has a big constructor that creates the level, the player, the weapons etc.

I was under the impression that if I then did this

```
removeChild(_gameWorld);
_gameWorld = null;
```

because the GameWorld object is now unreachable, and therefore so is the level, the players and everything else referenced from inside it, the entire thing would be garbage collected. This seems not to be the case. Instead I'm finding that elements of the old gameworld are still attempting to function.

I wondered if it might be because some of these elements have event listeners in them, listening to other elements, 'this' or sometimes 'stage'. I've tried setting them to be weakly referenced, but it hasn't helped, and my understanding is that an event listener holding a reference to the stage for example shouldn't prevent that object from being garbage collected anyway.

For debugging I'd like to have the ability to restart the whole game very quickly, so I was hoping it would be as simple as

```
removeChild(_gameWorld);
_gameWorld = null;
_gameWorld = new GameWorld();
addChild(_gameWorld);
```

Rather than having to somehow meticulously disassemble the whole thing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: it could be an issue with listeners not being released, but hard to say without seeing some code - posting your GameWorld class would be a good start (edited to remove non-relevant code if its large)

Comment: I've no idea what might or might not be relevant. It's not too large but I've got a lot of other classes it uses which are quite large. I've gone through all my classes now and set absolutely every event listener to be weakly referenced, no help.

Comment: Are you using addChild to add stuff to anything outside of GameWorld (eg: the stage)?

Comment: Nope. I'm passing a reference to GameWorld from within it (using 'this') to a few of the constructors of other classes, so they each have references to each other, what about that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make a function inside every class you use, say destroy(), which you call every time when the object is no longer used (or you can add event listener for stage remove of the object if you don't explicitly call remove/destroy).

Inside this destroy() function, remove ALL event listeners manually, and empty all class level lists like : Vectors, Arrays and etc. Also, all class level variables that are of reference type - set them to null.

Comment: I've started having a go at this and it is a MASSIVE pain, and I don't understand why it is necessary. If GameWorld is unreachable and all the listeners are weakly referenced, why isn't it being removed?

Comment: @Jim Sreven weak reference doesn't guarantee you that the listener will be removed, especially ENTER_FRAME events. So it's best practice to manually remove all of it. Also, reference type variables are often cause for memory leak, so make sure you set all of them to null. And I mean ALL of them, in the main class, and all other classes - if the object they are referencing is still alive, GC will not clean that object.